# Show content when hovering over div in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, freewalljs

I am using [Freewall JS](http://vnjs.net/www/project/freewall/) plugin to generate a mosaic image grid. I am also applying a background overlay color with `opacity: 0.7` and when you hover over it, the background overlay color becomes clear with `opacity: 0.2`

I also have content inside each block, I've set it to display none by default but I can't get it to appear on hover.

The grid items are being generated from the javascript so the HTML is an empty div with an id

**jsFiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/3o63eor8/3/

```
<div id="freewall" class="free-wall"></div>
```

The CSS

```
.overlay-background {
    position: relative;
}
.overlay-background:before{
    position: absolute;
    content:" ";
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display: none;
    z-index:0;
}
.overlay-background:before{
    display: block;
}
.dark:before {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
.free-wall {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#freewall .dark:hover::before {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
#freewall .freewall-content span {
    display: none
}
#freewall .freewall-content:hover span {
    display: block
}
```

The JS that generates the image blocks automatically, I've added my css classes to the `temp` string

```
var temp = "<div class='brick overlay-background dark' style='width:{width}px; " +
    "height: {height}px; " +
    "background-image: url(assets/images/posts/post-{index}.jpg); " +
    "background-repeat: no-repeat; " +
    "background-size: cover; " +
    "background-position: center center;" +
    "background-color: {color}'>" +
    "<div class='v-center text-center freewall-content'><span><i class='fa fa-search'></i></span></div>" +
    "</div>";

var colour = [
    "rgb(142, 68, 173)",
    "rgb(243, 156, 18)",
    "rgb(211, 84, 0)",
    "rgb(0, 106, 63)",
    "rgb(41, 128, 185)",
    "rgb(192, 57, 43)",
    "rgb(135, 0, 0)",
    "rgb(39, 174, 96)"
];

var w = 1, h = 1, html = '', color = '', limitItem = 17;
for (var i = 0; i < limitItem; ++i) {
    h = 1 + 3 * Math.random() << 0;
    w = 1 + 3 * Math.random() << 0;
    color = colour[colour.length * Math.random() << 0];
    html += temp.replace(/\{height\}/g, h*150).replace(/\{width\}/g, w*150).replace("{color}", color).replace("{index}", i + 1);
}
$("#freewall").html(html);
```

Comment: Can You Provide JSFiddle

Comment: There you go https://jsfiddle.net/3o63eor8/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is how your HTML is structured. Technically, the `div` where `class="brick overlay-background dark"` is on top of the `freewall-content` so you never actually hover over it. You can see this through the developer tools (f12) and looking at the live DOM tree

Change the css selector to look like -

```
.brick.overlay-background.dark:hover .freewall-content .span {
    display: block
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3o63eor8/8/

Answer (score 1):

Don't use display: none;

Make the opacity of the parent element 1 and then lower the opacity to so the content can be visible.

I think you're overcomplicating something that has a simple solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/erwdepqp/

```
.brick {
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px
    }
    .overlay-background {
        position: relative;
    }
    .overlay-background:before{
        position: absolute;
        content:" ";
        top:0;
        left:0;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        display: none;
        z-index:0;
    }
    .overlay-background:before{
        display: block;
    }
    .dark:before {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 1);
    }
    .dark:hover::before {
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    .freewall-content:hover span {
        display: block;
    }
```